# Accessing Concourse REST API from resource

Tags: concourse, concourse-fly, concourse-resource-types

I am trying to write a custom Concourse resource (in Python) that accesses the Concourse instance's REST API for information. I'm stuck at obtaining the bearer token at login. The issue is that when I follow the gist of this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

## Variables required  #need to update these to take inputs for getting token per team and target.
CONCOURSE_URL="http://localhost:8080"
CONCOURSE_USER="test"
CONCOURSE_PASSWORD="test"
CONCOURSE_TEAM="test"
CONCOURSE_TARGET="my-concourse"

function get_token() {
  ## Create a file named token that will be used to read and write tokens
  touch token

  ## extract the LDAP authentication url and write to token file
  LOCAL_AUTH_URL=$CONCOURSE_URL$(curl -b token -c token -L "$CONCOURSE_URL/sky/login" -s | grep "/sky/issuer/auth/local" | awk -F'"' '{print $4}')
  echo "url is $LOCAL_AUTH_URL"
  # login using username and password while writing to the token file
  curl -s -o /dev/null -b token -c token  -L --data-urlencode "login=$CONCOURSE_USER" --data-urlencode "password=$CONCOURSE_PASSWORD" "$LOCAL_AUTH_URL"

  ATC_BEARER_TOKEN=`grep 'Bearer' token | cut -d\   -f2 | sed 's/"$//'`
  echo $ATC_BEARER_TOKEN
}
```

there are many redirects involved, and at least some of them refer to the concourse instance as being at http://localhost:8080, which does not work from inside the docker container of the resource.

So I wanted to parametrize the external base url and explicitly give it in resource config. Manually handling the redirects and rewriting the local IP into the URL fails at the last "approval" step with a code 400, probably because it looks like some kind of a cross-domain attack.

The environment variable ATC_EXTERNAL_URL is always localhost:8080 and I suspect that this is also used when forming out the redirect urls. Can this be set somewhere?

I'm bad at golang, but it seems to me that https://github.com/concourse/concourse-pipeline-resource calls the fly binary to achieve some kind of login from inside a resource. Can't say I can get what it does and how.

All help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The env var `$ATC_EXTERNAL_URL` most likely corresponds to the external url specified when you start Concourse, so yes, it can (and if you're using external auth like Github or OAuth, must) be changed. You're correct in assuming that it's used to construct callback URLs.

Also, I don't want to be That Guy(TM), but the Concourse REST API is not public and is subject to change at any time. What are you trying to do that you can't get from the `fly` CLI? Your resource could call the `ATC_EXTERNAL_URL` to get the fly CLI when it's needed then execute commands that way.

Comment: "Concourse REST API is not public and is subject to change at any time."

Is this still true in 2023?